# Divide rows by date and by group SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with SQL. I found similar one [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393027/divide-rows-with-date-in-sql-server-2014), but not exactly the same. I would like to separate the dates which overlaps. For example I have in the first row START_DATE 2014-08-06 and END_DATE 2014-10-06. We can see that the dates from the second and the third row are inside this period of time from first row but I have to do it separately on `STORE_ID` and `INDEX_ID`. The price should be taken from inner period. I can't modify this code. Can you help me?

My table looks like this:

```
declare @t table  (STORE_ID INT, 
                  INDEX_ID INT,
                  START_DATE datetime,
                  END_DATE datetime, 
                  GROSS_SALES_PRICE decimal(10,2)
             );

 insert into @t 
 values (1,20,'2014-08-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-06 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
 (1,20,'2014-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-09 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
 (1,20,'2014-09-10 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
 (1,20,'2014-10-07 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 23:59:59.000', 34.99),
 (1,22,'2014-08-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-06 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
 (1,22,'2014-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-09 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
 (1,22,'2014-09-10 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
 (1,22,'2014-10-07 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 23:59:59.000', 34.99),
 (2,20,'2014-08-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-06 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
 (2,20,'2014-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-09 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
 (2,20,'2014-09-10 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
 (2,20,'2014-10-07 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 23:59:59.000', 34.99)
```

And the desired output:

```
  declare @t2 table (STORE_ID INT, 
                    INDEX_ID INT, 
                    START_DATE datetime,
                    END_DATE datetime, 
                    GROSS_SALES_PRICE decimal(10,2)
                   );

 insert into @t2 
 values (1,20,'2014-08-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-05 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
   (1,20,'2014-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-09 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
   (1,20,'2014-09-10 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
   (1,20,'2014-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-06 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
   (1,20,'2014-10-07 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 23:59:59.000', 34.99),
   (1,22,'2014-08-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-05 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
   (1,22,'2014-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-09 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
   (1,22,'2014-09-10 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
   (1,22,'2014-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-06 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
   (1,22,'2014-10-07 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 23:59:59.000', 34.99),
   (2,20,'2014-08-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-05 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
   (2,20,'2014-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-09 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
   (2,20,'2014-09-10 00:00:00.000', '2014-09-30 23:59:59.000', 32.99),
   (2,20,'2014-10-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-10-06 23:59:59.000', 29.99),
   (2,20,'2014-10-07 00:00:00.000', '2049-12-31 23:59:59.000', 34.99)
```

So the code should work like in the topic I attached, but it should do it separately on every `STORE_ID` and `INDEX_ID`.

Comment: `same think as in that topic` ... no, your question needs to stand on its own two feet.  Please edit your question and provide a clear problem statement.

Comment: done, i think it is clear now. sorry

Comment: Show Your expected OutPut

Comment: table t2 contains the desired output

Comment: Why price in the 4th row is 29.99, not 34.99 (in t2)? I do not understand which row have the highest priority

Comment: Because price should be taken from inner period if one exists. The 4th row is the end of the period from the first row and it is not covered by any other inner period.

Comment: @Masher it's covered by the 4th row in t1. Period from 2014-10-01 to 2014-10-06 is covered by 1st and 4th rows. Why you select 1st?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I changed the input table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH Preprocessed AS (
    SELECT STORE_ID, INDEX_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE,
        NEXT_START_DATE = FIRST_VALUE(START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY STORE_ID, INDEX_ID ORDER BY START_DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING),
        MAX_END_DATE    = MAX(END_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY STORE_ID, INDEX_ID ORDER BY START_DATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
    FROM @t
)
SELECT 
    STORE_ID, INDEX_ID, START_DATE,
    END_DATE_NEW = IIF(NEXT_START_DATE IS NOT NULL AND NEXT_START_DATE < END_DATE, DATEADD(SECOND, -1, NEXT_START_DATE), END_DATE)
FROM Preprocessed

UNION ALL

SELECT STORE_ID, INDEX_ID, 
    START_DATE  = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, END_DATE),
    END_DATE    = IIF(NEXT_START_DATE < MAX_END_DATE, DATEADD(SECOND, -1, NEXT_START_DATE), MAX_END_DATE)
FROM Preprocessed
WHERE (NEXT_START_DATE IS NULL OR NEXT_START_DATE > DATEADD(SECOND, 1, END_DATE))   -- End of the range
    AND (END_DATE < MAX_END_DATE)                                                   -- Check if need to add new record after range
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```