# SQL Windowed functions Error - Looking for a code fix / suggestion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Updated question

I want to get the COUNTS and SUMS of LOT items numbers. The lots have different BATCH numbers, each BATCH can have different REVISION numbers. REVISION numbers have to be the MAX(Revision) number within each batch number for PROPOSALSTATUS that are "awarded" or "closed/cancelled". If the proposal status is "ROR Awarded" or "OAA Awarded" then all values me be counted.

THIS is what I'm trying to use. Because of my MAX(revision) over statements I keep receiving a Windowed Functions Error. I do not understand how to work around that. If someone could take one of these counts and one sum and show me how to work around it would be awesome.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(PB.lot)AS SubmittedCount, 

COUNT(DISTINCT MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.lot,pb.batch,(CASE WHEN pb.ProposalStatus = 'Closed/Cancelled'   OR pb.proposalstatus = 'Awarded' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) +
COUNT(CASE WHEN pb.proposalstatus = 'ROR Awarded'  or pb.ProposalStatus = 'OAA Awarded' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)AS DecidedCount,

COUNT(DISTINCT MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.lot, pb.batch,(CASE WHEN pb.proposalstatus = 'OAA Partially Awarded' OR pb.ProposalStatus = 'ROR Partially Awarded'  OR pb.proposalstatus = 'OAA Proposal Submitted - Pending Award' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) +
COUNT(CASE WHEN pb.ProposalStatus = 'Awarded' OR pb.ProposalStatus = 'ROR Awarded' OR pb.ProposalStatus = 'OAA Awarded' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS WonCount,

COUNT(CASE WHEN pb.ProposalStatus = 'Disapproved' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS DisapprovedCount,

SUM(pb.materialvalue + pb.shippingValue)AS Total, 

SUM(DISTINCT MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.lot,pb.batch,(CASE WHEN pb.ProposalStatus = 'Closed/Cancelled'   OR pb.proposalstatus = 'Awarded' THEN pb.MaterialValue + Pb.ShippingValue ELSE NULL END))) +
SUM(CASE WHEN pb.proposalstatus = 'ROR Awarded'  or pb.ProposalStatus = 'OAA Awarded' THEN pb.MaterialValue + Pb.ShippingValue ELSE NULL END)AS DecidedTotal,

SUM(DISTINCT MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.lot,pb.batch,(CASE WHEN pb.proposalstatus = 'OAA Partially Awarded' OR pb.ProposalStatus = 'ROR Partially Awarded'  OR pb.proposalstatus = 'OAA Proposal Submitted - Pending Award' THEN pb.MaterialValue + Pb.ShippingValue ELSE NULL END))) +
SUM(CASE WHEN pb.ProposalStatus = 'Awarded' OR pb.ProposalStatus = 'ROR Awarded' OR pb.ProposalStatus = 'OAA Awarded' THEN pb.MaterialValue + Pb.ShippingValue ELSE NULL END) AS WonTotal,

SUM(CASE WHEN pb.proposalStatus = 'Disapproved' THEN pb.MaterialValue + Pb.ShippingValue ELSE NULL END) AS DisapprovedTotal


FROM  DB1 ps  
INNER JOIN DB2 pb
ON ps.Title = pb.Lot

WHERE  (pb.ProposalSubmitted IS NOT NULL)  AND BATCH <> 6 AND (ps.Contract LIKE 'CLS')
GROUP BY pb.lot, pb.batch, pb.revision, pb.proposalstatus
ORDER BY pb.lot
```

Realistically -  I want to be able to put this into a small table that looks like this: 
[Sample Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxP6N.png)

[Final Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR7iK.png)

```
    declare @pb table
              (lot, proposalStatus, proposalSubmitted datetime,
               revision, materialValue, shippingValue, batch);

    insert into @pb
    values ('1', 'Awarded', '5/23/2016', '0', '200', '100', '2'),
           ('1', 'Awarded', '5/23/2016', '0', '200', '300', '4'),   
           ('2', 'Pending', '  ', '1', '100', '400', '2'),
           ('3', 'Cancelled', '6/12/2016', '4', '200', '100', '4'),
           ('4', 'Awarded', '5/12/2016', '2', '300', '100', '3')

    declare @ps table
                   (title, contract);
    insert into ps
values ('1', 'CLS'),
       ('1', 'AFC'),
       ('2', 'CLS'),
       ('3', 'AFC'),
       ('4', 'CLS')
```

**My join is on pb.lot = ps.title**

Comment: What is your input sample dataset and expected output?

Comment: Sorry, just added it. I don't have enough rep for it to show in the page but the link there says sample in put and teh final results table is a image of my results.

Comment: Sample input still shows blank

Comment: Fixed - the input. Sorry about that.

Comment: use this to turn your tables into text: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: What's the best method for keeping the formatting after i turn it into a text table? doing the 4 indentations doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Declare a table variable and generate `insert` statements to populate it - this code is the best input data for us. Look at this question and it's sample data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407529/divide-rows-by-date-and-by-group-sql

Comment: Does that table work? It mimics what i'm working with very closely.

Comment: Added the PK / FK  join by pb.lot = ps.title. Sorry forgot that initially.

Comment: Have you any problems? I think you code is good. You can replace `OR` with `IN`: `pb.proposalstatus IN ('Partially Awarded', 'OAA Partially Awarded', 'ROR Partially Awarded', 'Proposal Submitted - Pending Award', 'OAA Proposal Submitted - Pending Award')`

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "pb" or the user-defined function or aggregate "pb.batch", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: First code example will not work, what about second? It's OK

Comment: See how in the first code example I'm looking for the Max(revision) ? Or newest revision? I need to only count and / sum based on the newest revisions when they fit into certan proposal status. Second sample code works - but does not include just the newest revision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146165/discussion-between-nate-and-mikhail-lobanov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to calculate MaxRevision Count, replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` if you want to count all max revisions (not first only):

```
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT *,
        IsMaxRevision = IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PB.lot,PB.batch ORDER BY Revision DESC) = 1, 1, 0)
    FROM @ps        PS
    INNER JOIN @pb  PB ON ps.Title = pb.Lot
)
SELECT 
    lot, batch,
    DecidedCount        = SUM(CASE WHEN proposalstatus IN ('ROR Awarded', 'OAA Awarded') THEN 1
                                   WHEN proposalstatus IN ('Closed/Cancelled', 'Awarded') THEN IsMaxRevision
                              END),

    SubmittedCount      = COUNT(lot),
    OutstandingCount    = COUNT(CASE WHEN proposalstatus IN ('Partially Awarded', 'OAA Partially Awarded', 'ROR Partially Awarded', 'Proposal Submitted - Pending Award', 'OAA Proposal Submitted - Pending Award') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    WonCount            = COUNT(CASE WHEN ProposalStatus IN ('Awarded', 'ROR Awarded', 'OAA Awarded') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    DisapprovedCount    = COUNT(CASE WHEN ProposalStatus = 'Disapproved' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),

    Total               = SUM(materialvalue + shippingValue), 
    DecidedTotal        = SUM(CASE WHEN proposalstatus IN ('Closed/Cancelled', 'Awarded', 'ROR Awarded', 'OAA Awarded') THEN materialvalue + shippingValue ELSE NULL END),
    OutstandingTotal    = SUM(CASE WHEN proposalstatus IN ('Partially Awarded', 'OAA Partially Awarded', 'ROR Partially Awarded', 'Proposal Submitted - Pending Award', 'OAA Proposal Submitted - Pending Award') THEN materialvalue + shippingValue ELSE NULL END),
    WonTotal            = SUM(CASE WHEN proposalstatus IN ('Awarded', 'ROR Awarded', 'OAA Awarded') THEN materialvalue + shippingValue ELSE NULL END),
    DisapprovedTotal    = SUM(CASE WHEN proposalStatus = 'Disapproved' THEN MaterialValue + ShippingValue ELSE NULL END) 
FROM Data   D
GROUP BY lot, batch
```

Comment: Can I use the WITH Data AS command and keep my case statement? Also, does that command allow me to do a SUM from those rows?

Comment: Yes, `WITH` here is a simple subquery, you can query it (`Data`) as all other tables. And even `UPDATE` it!

Comment: I'm going to try it. WIll let you know in a bit how that worked out.

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to format it with my case statement. Any chance you can look above to my reworded question and see if it makes more sense now? The sample code could be viewed as PSEUDO code.

Comment: I edited my question to solve task in the way I understand it

Comment: Look at DecidedCount

Comment: Mikhail, is this using a CTE to solve the problem I was having? I haven't used a "WITH" expression before.

Comment: I think your problem is determine if row is max revision, `IsMaxRevision = IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PB.lot,PB.batch ORDER BY Revision DESC) = 1, 1, 0)` should solve it. I use `WITH` only for shorten code

Comment: That makes sense to get the counts - How does that translate to summing the values in the later ones?
DecidedTotal        = SUM(CASE WHEN proposalstatus IN ('Closed/Cancelled', 'Awarded', 'ROR Awarded', 'OAA Awarded') THEN materialvalue + shippingValue ELSE NULL END),

Comment: `SUM CASE WHEN IsMaxRevision = 1 AND proposalstatus IN ( ... ) THEN materialvalue + shippingValue ... `

Comment: Ohhhhhh. I understand what you did. You are use the CTE to loop through each one and assign a value of '1' when it's the max revision number. THen when I get to the sum values if that value was 1 then it loops through and uses my original materialValue + shippingValue.

Comment: I fixed the code - re-ran it. While the CTE works well in terms of looping through. It's still showing me every revision inside of each batch number instead of just the newest revision. Thoughts?

Comment: Window function does not filter something, it's only checks if row is max revision. You should filter rows manually

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MAX(pb.revision) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.lot,pb.batch(CASE WHEN pb.ProposalStatus = 'Closed/Cancelled' OR pb.proposalstatus = 'Awarded' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)))
```

You are missing a comma after "pb.batch".

Comment: Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.
-----This pops up when I added that comma behind pb.batch